# Receiving list of hubs with Autodesk Forge API

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I am trying to use the Autodesk forge API for C# to get a list of Hubs.
This is what I have done so far:

```
HubsApi api = new HubsApi();
Hubs hubs = api.GetHubs();
```

Pretty simple. But when I do so, I get an exception wicht complains, that one cannot convert from `DynamicJsonResponse` to `Hubs`. I think, this is because I receive two warnings in my response string and so it is not a Hub Object any longer. The warning looks like this:

```
"warnings":[  
        {  
           "Id":null,
           "HttpStatusCode":"403",
           "ErrorCode":"BIM360DM_ERROR",
           "Title":"Unable to get hubs from BIM360DM EMEA.",
           "Detail":"You don't have permission to access this API",
           "AboutLink":null,
           "Source":[  

           ],
           "meta":[  

           ]
        }
```

All of this is wrapped in an Dictionary with four entries and only two of them are data. However, according to Autodesk, this warning can be ignored.

So after that I tried to convert it in a Dictionary and only select the data entry

```
HubsApi api = new HubsApi();
DynamicJsonResponse resp = api.GetHubs();
DynamicDictionary hubs = (DynamicDictionary)resp.Dictionary["data"];
```

Then I looped through it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < hubs.Dictionary.Count && bim360hub == null; i++)
{
    string hub = hubs.Dictionary.ElementAt(i).ToString();
    [....]
}
```

But the string `hub` isn't an json-hub either. It is an array which looks like this:

```
[
  0,
  {
    "type": "hubs",
    "id": "****",
    "attributes": {...},
    "links": {...},
    "relationships": {...},
  }
]
```

And the second element in the array is my hub. I know, how I can select the second element. But there must be a much easier to get the list of hubs.
In an example in the references it seemd to work with these simple two lines of code:

```
HubsApi api = new HubsApi();
Hubs hubs = api.GetHubs();
```

Any ideas, how I manage to get my hubs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider using the Async version of those methods,  avoid using **non-async** calls as it causes your desktop app to freeze (while is connecting) or allocates more resources on ASP.NET.

The following [function](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/data.management-csharp-sample/blob/master/data.management-csharp-sample/Controllers/DataManagementTreeController.cs#L92) is part of [this sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/data.management-csharp-sample), which lists all hubs, projects and files under a user account. It's a good place to start. Note it's organizing the Hubs in a `TreeNode` list, which is compatible with [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/).

```
private async Task<IList<TreeNode>> GetHubsAsync()
{
  IList<TreeNode> nodes = new List<TreeNode>();

  HubsApi hubsApi = new HubsApi();
  hubsApi.Configuration.AccessToken = AccessToken;

  var hubs = await hubsApi.GetHubsAsync();
  string urn = string.Empty;
  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> hubInfo in new DynamicDictionaryItems(hubs.data))
  {
    string nodeType = "hubs";
    switch ((string)hubInfo.Value.attributes.extension.type)
    {
      case "hubs:autodesk.core:Hub":
        nodeType = "hubs";
        break;
      case "hubs:autodesk.a360:PersonalHub":
        nodeType = "personalhub";
        break;
      case "hubs:autodesk.bim360:Account":
        nodeType = "bim360hubs";
        break;
    }
    TreeNode hubNode = new TreeNode(hubInfo.Value.links.self.href, (nodeType == "bim360hubs" ? "BIM 360 Projects" : hubInfo.Value.attributes.name), nodeType, true);
    nodes.Add(hubNode);
  }

  return nodes;
}
```